# Executing PHP Directly From the Command Line

Tags: php

I've browsed quite a bit, but I'm unable to come up with a solution. I'm attempting to execute a mixed PHP/HTML stream *directly* from the command line, not from a file. I'm aware of the command line switches, -f (to execute from a physical file), and -r (to execute PHP only). Basically, I'm looking for the following functionality:

```
php -x "<html><head></head><body><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></body></html>"
```

Note that *-x* is not a valid switch, and the argument is an arbitrary stream of characters with mixed HTML and PHP. The output of this program, would ideally be:

```
<html><head></head><body>Hello World</body></html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
echo "<html><head></head><body><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></body></html>" | php
```

Note that the first echo is a bash echo, not a php echo.

Comment: Simple and straight, +1 for me.

Comment: @user1 - Thanks! Go figure I was overcomplicating it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the code to standard in, without any command line switches:

```
echo '<html><?php echo "hello world"; ?>' | php
```